# Удалить товар с корзины без перезагрузки?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Почему удаляется только при перезагрузке страницы?
Удаление при помощи очистки сессии
`if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_GET['id']]);`
Вывод продукта и там же кнопка удаления

```html
<?php foreach (reset($data) as $item => $value) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="files/products/<? echo $value->filename ?>" width="80" height="50"></td>
                <td><a href="?module=product&id=<?php echo $value->id ?>"><?php echo $value->name ?></a></td>
                <td><input style="width:80px;" class="form-control" type="number" name="amount" value="<?php echo $value->cart_amount  ?>" ></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->price ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->cart_amount * $value->price  ?></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger lii" name="del" data-id="<?=$value->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> удалить</button></td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $sum += $value->cart_amount * $value->price -1;
            $_SESSION['total_price_id'] = $sum;?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

```js
<script>
    $('.lii').on('click',function(e){ //
        var $button = $(e.targert);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/cart',
            data:{id:$(this).data('id')},
            success:function(){
                $button.closest(".product").remove();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже вы не то удаляете

```
$button.closest(".product").remove();
```

удалить ближайший объект с классом  product - но в коде таких нет. Скорее всего вам надо удалить tr ряд таблицы с данными, т.е. что-то вроде

```
$button.parents("tr:first").remove();
```

Comment: тоже не исчезает. Не как это Ajax не разберу особенно CRUD без перезагрузки

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Ajax нормально выполняется? Попробуйте добавить строку     `console.log('Получилось')` в success от ajax. Если в консоле это сообщение появляется, то ajax работает и надо только разобраться, как и что удалить в хтмл коде страницы.

Comment: Блин. Ошибка была в $(e.targert). Ну хоть нашел. Все работает спасибо